# Custom toolbar in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

[image]

I am trying to get this design, but the content is not collapsing. I need tabs to be under the toolbar when scrolling, currently, I set two buttons for collapsing layout for testing when, but the content is not scrolling now. What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should add toolbar outside the CoordinatorLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.MainFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin"
            android:elevation="@dimen/toolbarElevation"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_overflow"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu_border"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_message"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_message"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_search"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/img_overflow"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_search"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_message"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/img_overflow"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/vouch"
                    android:textColor="@color/action_bar_color"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_contacts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="View Contacts"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_edit_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Edit Profile"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you have to make toolbar sticky?

Comment: What do you mean ? It should not be moved.

Comment: if you does not want to make `Toolbar` sticky means it will collapse with `CollapsingToolbar` in this case only `TabLayout` will saw after sroll

Comment: @ShubhamVala no I want it wo be sticky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This if you does not want to make `Toolbar` sticky means it will collapse with `CollapsingToolbar`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/toolbarElevation"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"  <== Add this line 
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

if you want `Toolbar` to be sticky. then, move your `Toolbar`out of the main `CoordinateLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ui.fragments.MainFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/toolbarElevation"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_overflow"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_menu_border"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_message"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_message"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_search"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/img_overflow"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_search"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_message"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/img_overflow"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/vouch"
            android:textColor="@color/action_bar_color"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_contacts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="View Contacts"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_edit_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Edit Profile"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not working when I replace the fragmetn and then press back?Do you know the reason?

Comment: I does not get your point please explain further. you have take collapsing toolbar in fragment?

Comment: Yeah currently I am displaying this view in fragment,which is in activity container,and when I replace the fragment with another one,it's not scrolling.